# Matrix Diagonal Difference

Tags: matrix, clojure

**Problem**

Given a square matrix of size `N×N`, calculate the absolute difference between the sums of its diagonals.

**Input Format**

The first line contains a single integer, `N`. The next `N` lines denote the matrix's rows, with each line containing `N` space-separated integers describing the columns.

**Output Format**

Print the absolute difference between the two sums of the matrix's diagonals as a single integer.

**Sample Input**

```
3
11 2 4
4 5 6
10 8 -12
```

**Sample Output**

```
15
```

**Code**

```
(ns hackerrank.core
  [:require [clojure.string :as s]])

(defn get-diagonal-sums-reducer
  [n]
  (fn
    [sums [line-number line]]
    (let
      [primary (nth line line-number)
       secondary (nth line (- n (+ 1 line-number)))]
      (assoc
        sums
        :primary (+ primary (:primary sums))
        :secondary (+ secondary (:secondary sums))))))

(let
  [n (Integer/parseInt (read-line))
   matrix (for
            [_ (range n)]
            (mapv #(Integer/parseInt %) (s/split (read-line) #"\s+")))
   matrix-enumerated (map-indexed vector matrix)
   sums (reduce
          (get-diagonal-sums-reducer n)
          {:primary 0 :secondary 0}
          matrix-enumerated)
   difference (- (:primary sums) (:secondary sums))]
  (println (max difference (- difference))))
```

Couple questions in particular:

- can I avoid the `get-diagonal-sums-reducer` somehow? I'm only using it so that it closes over `n`.
- am I doing this as lazily as possible or is there any place I'm using vectors when seqs would have worked?
- is there a much less verbose way to do this? Doesn't feel like this would be as complicated in Python.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Could you have avoided get-diagonal-sums-reducer?

You probably could have used partial if you wanted, though I'm not sure it ends up that much better:

```clj
(defn diagnoal-sums-reducer [n sums [line-number line]]
  ...)

(reduce (partial diagonal-sums-reducer n) ...)
```

#### Is there a much less verbose way to do this.

I think there is.  I can see why you've tried to use reduce, but your reducer is doing way more than it should be.  Essentially, there's 3 things it's doing:

- Calculating the coordinates of the  diagonals for the line.
- Getting the values of those coordinates.
- Summing the values together with the previous values.

There might be some situations where you'd need to do all of those things in a single reduce, but I don't think this is one of those cases.  It's also complicated by having to do this for both the primary *and* the secondary cases.

It ends up much simpler if you split the whole process out into the individual steps:

```clj
(defn sum [x] (apply + x))

(let [n 3
      matrix [[11 2 4]
              [4 5 6]
              [10 8 -12]]

      ;; Build up a list of coordinates for the diagonals.
      primary-coords (for [i (range n)] [i i])
      secondary-coords (for [i (range n)] [(- n i 1) i])

      ;; Extract the values of those coordinates
      primaries (map #(get-in matrix %) primary-coords)
      secondaries (map #(get-in matrix %) secondary-coords)]

    ;; Sum them, take the absolute difference
    (Math/abs (- (sum primaries) (sum secondaries))))
```

Answer (score 0):

## Is there a much less verbose way to do this?

```
(defn diagonalDifference [a]
  (Math/abs (- (reduce + (map #(apply nth %) (map vector a (range 0 (count a)))))
               (reduce + (map #(apply nth %) (map vector a (range (dec (count a)) -1 -1)))))))
```

### Explanation

The sum of the first diagonal is:

```
(reduce + (map #(apply nth %) (map vector a (range 0 (count a)))))
```

Going through this from the inside to the outside:

1. Create a sequence of x-coordinates for each diagonal `range 0 (count a)`
2. We zip this sequence with the matrix. The result is `([[11 2 4] 0] [[4 5 6] 1] [[10 8 -12] 2])` for the *hackerrank* example matrix.
3. Now we apply the `nth` function to each vector in this sequence using `map` obtaining the diagonal `[11 5 -12]`
4. We sum it up using `reduce`

The other diagonal is calculated exactly the same way, only the range is different. The rest should be clear.

> Note: I tried factoring out some redundancies with `letfn`, but for me this is more readable.